# At which time static variable fails?

Tags: c#, static-variables

i have used one static variable and my static variable default value is `1`. then this variable value change based on user login..and my static variable value used for changing theme based on user login.

```
public static int theme = 1;
```

i have checked 5 user login at the same time it's working fine but i want to know when millions of user login at the same time in my site whether this static variable fails or not?

please give me suggestion

regards,
jatin

Comment: what do you mean by _fail_ ?

Comment: Just like with any resource that isn't explicitly thread-safe you have to use proper synchronization mechanisms to access it concurrently.

Comment: you are talking about login in asp.net?

Comment: Not a good idea to use static variables on the web portal. Use constant if you don't want this value to be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention a `static` variable, and you mention multiple users. This is an alarm bell, because the entire point of a `static` variable is that there is exactly **one** value (*caveat*, see below). It will work fine if all your users always have exactly the same `theme` (i.e. it is a global configuration setting); but: it this is meant to be a per-user setting, it should be a property of your user model, or some other per-user storage (cookies, session-state, etc).

The *caveat* here is `[ThreadStatic]`; but that *really* doesn't change anything in your scenario, especially if this is asp.net (since threads are not synonymous with either users or requests).

Comment: In my case session and cookie are not working please give me another solution

Comment: @JatinGadhiya define "not working"; that sounds simply like you've implemented them badly - they should work fine. I already suggested another option: associate the theme with your user object model, but that requires a working identity concept, which requires working cookies

Comment: i am using in nopcommerce and in nopcommerce theme changes based on dependency register and dependency register page does not able to use session and cookie.

Comment: @JatinGadhiya pro tip: if you are tied to a specific framework that has unusual behaviours: **say that at the start**. I do not know what is / is not possible with that framework.

Answer (score 2):

If this is an asp.net site, which it sounds like it is, then you should not use a `static` variable for this.

The reason why you shouldn't use static is because it will not be unique to the user, it will be the same variable to all users that connect to your website (I believe it's actually unique to the application pool). That means that when one user changes it, then it will change for all other users too.

Use a session variable instead:

```
// Set.
Session["Theme"] = 1;

// Get.
int theme = (int)Session["Theme"];
```

For convenience you could wrap this in a static property...

```
public static int Theme
{
    get
    {
        if(Session["Theme"] == null)
            return 0;// Or an alternate default value.
        return (int)Session["Theme"];
    }
    set { Session["Theme"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: In my case session and cookie are not working please give me another solution

Comment: @JatinGadhiya: Why are they not working? They should work just fine. Are you using ASP.Net?

Comment: yes i am using in nopcommerce and in nopcommerce theme changes based on dependency register and dependency register page does not able to use session and cookie.